# Can I tell if an enemy is out of range?

Tags: elden-ring

I'm playing as an Astrologer, so my main means of attack is to cast spells from a distance, as I barely do any physical damage.

However, I noticed that my spells have a certain range, and firing them at enemies beyond that range does absolutely nothing. That's not a problem mid-battle, since the enemies are trying to get close and personal with me, while I'm trying to get away from them. It's problematic when I'm trying to hit them while they haven't spotted me yet, as this means I'll be wasting my FP for an attack that won't land.

So I was wondering, is there a way to tell whether an enemy is within range of my currently equipped spell?

Comment: I have no idea because I haven't played with magic, but: what happens if you lock on the enemies (pressing `R3`)? Can enemies still be out of range *while* locked-on?

Comment: @xtropicalsoothing, yes, they can. So far I've always locked on before firing. I was excepting the lock reticle to change color or something, but it didn't.

Comment: From my experience so far playing the Astrologer there is no range indicator, it's a hit or miss (quite literally)

Comment: There's no way to know if it's in / out range, it was like this since PS3's demon's. Like GameLikeBeaker said, it's a hit or miss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, as folks in the comments have pointed out, there is no indicator that a given spell will hit a targeted enemy from any given range. You will have to learn the spell ranges of each spell you plan to use and adjust your distance from enemies in combat accordingly in order to be effective with them.

Some spells have pitiful range, such as [Glintstone Pebble](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Glintstone+Pebble), while others have extremely high range, such as [Loretta's Greatbow](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Loretta%27s+Greatbow). While Glintstone Pebble's range is very short, it could still be useful in midgame due to its short cast speed, cheap FP cost, and ability to be repeatedly cast quickly.